# FlutterBloc: BlocListener not consuming emitted state

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

The bloc that is giving me trouble is the AuthBloc. Here is how it is initialised:

```
void main() {
  runApp(MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider<AuthBloc>(
          create: (_) => AuthBloc(),
        ),
        BlocProvider<SignUpBloc>(create: (_) => SignUpBloc()),
      ],
      child: ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (BuildContext context) => UserModel(), child: App())));
}
```

Here is where I need the state to be acted on, but in certain cases the bloc's listener is not called:

```
Widget home(BuildContext context) {
    // ignore: close_sinks
    var authBloc = BlocProvider.of<AuthBloc>(context);
    return BlocListener(
      bloc: authBloc,
      listener: (context, state) {

        UserModel userModel = Provider.of<UserModel>(context, listen: false);
        if (state is SignedInState) {
          userModel.updateUser(state.user);

          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(kHomeRoute);
        }
      },
      child: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

I know that the bloc is recieving the event, but when I yield the state, this bloc does not rebuild. Any thoughts on where I'm going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to provide your event, state and bloc class so people can help you